# SQL Inserts failing from one server and working from other server, due to locking

Tags: mysql, database, join, locking

I have two tables, with roughly 65-70 Million rows each, and ~25 columns each.
A few days back, we were running a Big update query on it which involved a join of these two tables.

something like this:

```
update A INNER JOIN B on a.some_fk=b.some_fk set A.field1=B.field1 where A.field1 is null;
```

This query took a big lock, and blocked a lot of queries, one of which is in question here.

The application has two servers, both sending the same query mentioned below

```
INSERT INTO A(X,Y,Z) VALUES(X,Y,Z)
```

But this query was consistently giving **Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction** from one of the machines and working a lot more times from the other one. 1:100 kind of a success ration from both machines.

Why did this happen, and why is this a function of who the caller is.
Both the machines have same configuration, same number of connections, same bandwidth, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind, sorry if you already thought of them:

1. Table has a different number of rows/matching values on server 1 compared to server 2
2. Table has different indexes or the indexes have different levels of fragmentation on the 2 servers
3. The 2 servers have different usage patterns, which mean that your locks have more competition on the 2nd server
4. The tables have a different lock escalation threshold on each server, or are on different page sizes or using different cache sizes

In general, I would say that if the query is so big you are filling log or causing performance issues, you should chunk up the update by e.g. looping round updating n rows at a time ( whatever number of rows is most conducive to completing without crashing.)